# IF statement count++ in android studio using java firebase

Tags: java, android, if-statement, firebase

How can i put a function regarding this one on java android fire-base. I am creating a chat app and i have a existing fire-base structure like this.let say i send a message "**Hello**".

```
Chat:
    Author:"name"
    Chat:"Hello"
```

I want to put push a function that it will count the number of message in every user. therefore it will be like this. let say i send a message saying **hi?** and **Be right back**

```
Chat:
    Author:"name"
    Chat:"hi?"
    numMessages: 1

Chat:
    Author:"name"
    Chat:"Be right back"
    numMessages: 2
```

I think it is *if statement* count++? but i try everything regarding this.ugh.
Java and Android masters hope you can give me some suggestions sir.

Comment: Maybe you could add a counter in your onClick, and  if you want, you can send that number to firebase, if you want. Simply initialize an int in your oncreate, and increase it on every button click

Comment: how was that.? i wonder i set an onClick on the send button that if you'll going to send a message it will save on the firebase as the example above . my problem is how to execute a oncreate button that has no Layout design , because it will just count the number of my message. ugh , what to do,@Amy

Comment: Do you want to count all messages, or just the messages of one user?

Comment: messages of one user @Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global int variable: `int counter = 0;`
In your onClick add: `counter++;`
Set counter to 0 whenever you want, if not it will count on and on - and is only set to 0 when your activity is recreated.

If you want to send it to firebase, you'll need to add the counter there to, and simply send it with your messages,update your Message.class with an int named "counter" (similiar to the Strings "author" and "message",send it will be sent and shown in your Chat.

Does this answer your question?

Update:

First, go into `Message.class` and add:

```
int counter;

public int getCounter(){
    return counter;
}

public void setCounter(int counter){
    this.counter = counter;
}
```

If you want to show the counter in your View, you can simply add another TextView in your `fragment_message.xml` or you can add it programatically in your message, in your `MessageAdapter.java` add in populateView:

```
//if you added an extra TextView in your fragment_message.xml
TextView counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourcounterid);

counter.setText(message.getCounter());

//if you want to add the number in your messageView:
messageView.setText(message.getMessage() + " " + message.getCounter());
```

So to your `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


private EditText editText;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    final Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://samp-is.firebaseio.com/");


    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(this, Message.class, R.layout.fragment_message, firebase.child("chat")));

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;

            Message message = new Message();

            message.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setText("");
            message.setAuthor("Name");
            message.setCounter(counter);
            firebase.child("chat").push().setValue(message);


        }
        });
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly, Firebase should add a Child "counter" to its database and update it with your counter value.
Does it work?

Comment: am going to show the full code of mine , look how is show.

Comment: i did put all the code ,  and it will show the problem , theres no problem regarding with code. it just i don know how to place the count++ on the onCLick to increase the number of the user everytime i send a message in a particular person.

Comment: Thanks @amy it helps me alot and it works. you took me out through the darkness lmao .thanks!

Comment: the numMessages does not show on the firebase btw, if i will put same like the author and message string . i will going to make a layout for that , which its not recommended .how was that?

Comment: I suggest you look over the firebase docs, it's explained there, I think: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html

Comment: do you have preferences regarding on how to put a notification inside a app , like popping up on a icon , like in facebook. i've searched for this references but non of the result answer my question, on how to put notification on a app. thanks!